# Two dimentional array, not printing proper element?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

It seems everything is correct but still when i print, it prints all elements as zero...please help me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define COL 4
#define ROW 3

int y[3][4] = {{1, 2, 3},
               {4, 5, 6},
               {7, 8, 9}
                        };        


int main()
{
   int i,j;

   for(i=0;i<=ROW;i++)
   {

      for(j=0;j<=COL;j++)
      {
          printf("Value at col %d and row %d, is : %d\n",COL,ROW,y[ROW][COL]);
      }
   }

 }
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems in your code:

- your loops count one element to far, they go from 0 **up to and including** ROW/COL, while your array go from 0 **to** COL/ROW. Use `for(i=0; i < ROW; i++)`. Notice the `<` instead of your `<=`! (same goes for the COL-loop)
- you swapped the rows and columns in your `printf()` statement, use first the column then the row.
- you did not use the variables in the `printf()`, use `printf("Value at col %d and row %d, is : %d\n",j,i, y[i][j]);` instead.
- your array only has 3 `COL`umns, instead of the `#defined` 4

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("Value at col %d and row %d, is : %d\n",i,j,y[i][j]);
```

You are using the ROW and COL as offsets instead of the loop variables

Answer (score 1):

Array elements are access by their index use i & j to access array elements, such that
i>=0 and i< ROW,
e.g.

```
printf("Col:%d, Row:%d, Value:%d", i, j,y[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

change

> printf("Value at col %d and row %d, is : %d\n",COL,ROW,y[ROW][COL]);

into

> printf("Value at col %d and row %d, is : %d\n",i,j, y[i][j]);

Also note that your array-dimensions are **3;4** and then initialized as **3;3** !

Answer (score 0):

```
      printf("Value at col %d and row %d, is : %d\n",COL,ROW,y[ROW][COL]);
```

With this, you are printing: `y[ROW][COL]` whereas you intended `y[i][j]`

You are also accessing out of bounds due to which it invokes undefined behaviour.

Your conditions should be: `i<ROw` and `j<COL` in the for loops.